kivymd app apk cannot connect with database.db file on mobile phone
I created a Kivymd app that connects with a sqlite3 database.db file. I compiled it with buildozer and it successfully worked fine and as I saw how buildozer works, the database file cannot be seen.  But that was the first testing, the final application of the app requires the database.db file to be transferred to the phone from a PC, so I placed it in the Download folder of the phone and edited the path in the python script. And now I keep getting sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to opendatabase file. This has set me on a path to understand adb better, runnning adb shell as root, sadly my phone is a production build and I can't expect everybody using the app to root their phones. I have tried different PATHS.

storage/self/primary/Download/database.db
sdcard/Download/database.db
storage/emulated/0/Dowload/data.db

Cause the database will be created on a PC then transferred to the phone, so i copied it to SD Card and running
$ adb shell and
$ ls -lah
I see how the phone links the sdcard to sdcard -\> /storage/self/primary and I am believing that is what is not allowing the app to read the file as I can't even assess it with adb, as I can't adb root.
chmod 777 database.db

doesn't change any permissions.
I also tried (as my adb can't run sudo or su)
chown everbody database.db
usermod -a -G database.db everybody
chmod u+w+x,g+w+x database.db

Still no success in changing any permissions.
Where or how can I copy this file to this phone so that it can easily be assessed by the app just by the correct location of the PATH being put in the Python script?  Android phones really have a lot of permission issues.
I have already also successfully used:
if platform == 'android':
    from android.permission import Permission, request_permissions, check_permissioin
    request_permission([Permisssion.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

at the top of the script which pop-ups successfully after the load splashscreen, I tap allow, so that works fine but the sqlite error still comes up after and the app crashes.  And when i uninstall the app i see that really the permissions where granted, so it can't be a permissions issue.
The phone i'm using is a Samsung Galaxy A02, running Android 11 and I am also using a Arch Linux x86_64 lts Kernel and VSCode IDE

Credit to @Lino. I just had to copy it with:
$ adb push database.db /data/local/tmp

then:
$ adb shell run-as org.test.app_name cp /data/local/tmp/database.db files/app

and then change the path in the python script to just 'database.db'. The copy can be confirmed by:
$ adb shell
$ run-as org.test.app_name
$ cd files/app
$ ls

All this is necessary because I have a production build phone without root access.
